# Office365 config issue on a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, office365, actionmailer

I have developed a Rails application with an ActionMailer. I want to send email through an Office365 mail server. 
To do so, I have configured the ActionMail in my environment.rb file as following:

```
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['outlook_email'],
  :password => ENV['outlook_password'],
  :domain => 'congrueit.com',
  :address => 'smtp.office365.com',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

When the application is supposed to send the e-mail, I get the following error:

```
554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message
```

To complete the description, I am positive that the issue comes from the server configuration because it was working fine while configured with a Sendgrid server.

Thank you in advance for your help.

BR,

Quentin

Comment: Have you already looked at [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69426f64-717d-47e0-aa1b-700903ee83cc/520-storedrv-error?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy) or [this](https://community.zammad.org/t/smtp-settings-doesnt-work-well-with-exchange-online/1509) or [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rails%22+5.2.0+STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;+Failed+to+process+message+due+to+a+permanent+exception+with+m). It seems "SendAsDeniedException" might be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will have a look at them.